# optional type parameter for constructor

Tags: c#

I have a class that works like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    MyClass(SomeOtherObject TheObject)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

As you can see, the constructor takes in an object as parameter. How do I change the constructor so that the object parameter becomes optional?

*Note: I did look on google, and most posts talk about an optional value parameter but I need an optional type parameter.*

Comment: No, you *don't* need an optional type parameter. It's just a parameter. At least, you haven't mentioned *anything* about generics, which is where type parameters come in...

Comment: create a different constructor without parameters...

Comment: @JonSkeet: if I write MyClass TheClass = new MyClass(); it doesn't work.

Comment: the only option C# will give you is to pass a default value to your parameter (and for a non-primitive type, it can only be null) and you have to write MyClass(SomeOtherObject TheObject = null)

Comment: For whoever downvoted, go ahead and try "optional type parameter for constructor" in google and you'll see that there's no real easy-to-find 1-liner answer that answers what this question asks.

Comment: @frenchie Really, because I find information on the topic highly easy to find in google as there is lots of information on the topic.

Comment: @Servy: try optional type parameter for constructor in google and you'll see that the first item that comes up is the link to this answer; that's how relevant google thinks this question is and if google says so then it must be true.

Comment: @frenchie That's because you're not using the proper terms.  It's not a "type parameter" that you want, you want a an optional arguement, or even an optional parameter.  An optional *type* parameter is entirely non-sensical and such a thing doesn't really exist.  If I only saw the title I might think you meant a generic argument, which would be a parameter that is a Type, and by "optional" you might be referring to type inference, but that's not possible in that context.  That your own question comes up when you use your own invented term is not surprising.

Comment: @Servy: right and if you don't know what the proper term is, then you use a different and inaccurate word until you know the proper term.

Comment: All you need to do is remove "type" from your search term, because it honestly has no business being there.  You just want an optional argument to a constructor, and searching for that will quickly lead you to all that you need to know.

Comment: Oh, and it's worth noting that even searching for "optional type parameter for constructor" in google *does* lead to helpful pages that contain the answer to this question.  And while this link is first, because it's the only place on the internet that uses that exact phrase (which is why you shouldn't generally search for phrases, you should search for keywords) skipping over it and looking at the next few results are all quite helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overload the constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
       ....
    }
    MyClass(SomeOtherObject TheObject)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
    MyClass(SomeOtherObject TheObject = null)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

In this way you omit the parameter on construction of the object.

```
var cls = new MyClass(); //NO PARAMETER SPECIFIED
```

In this way you have to manage internaly that the `field/property` you assign to `TheObject`  can become `null`, in this case.

Or simply use ctors ctors overloading:

```
public class MyClass
{
    MyClass(SomeOtherObject TheObject)
    {
       ....
    }

    MyClass() : this(null)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Will constructor overloading work?

```
public class MyClass
{
    MyClass(Object TheObject)
    {
    }

    MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```